How to use setNames on subelements of list
I found this question but it does not seem to work for me.
The task is simple. I have a list like the following, obtained from a data frame, and I want to setNames for the subelements:
mydf <- data.frame(Patient=rep(paste0('Pat', 1:3), 2), Cycle=rep(paste0('C', 1:2), each=3))
mylist <- sapply(mydf, unique)

The list looks like:
> mylist
$Patient
[1] "Pat1" "Pat2" "Pat3"

$Cycle
[1] "C1" "C2"

The only thing I want to do is to setNames for the subelements, so that they include the element name, resulting into this final list:
> mylist
$Patient
Patient-Pat1 Patient-Pat2 Patient-Pat3 
      "Pat1"       "Pat2"       "Pat3" 

$Cycle
Cycle-C1 Cycle-C2 
    "C1"     "C2" 

Now I could go through the elements one by one like this:
mylist[[1]] <- setNames(mylist[[1]], paste(names(mylist)[1], mylist[[1]], sep='-'))
mylist[[2]] <- setNames(mylist[[2]], paste(names(mylist)[2], mylist[[2]], sep='-'))
...

But I do not want that, since the list can have variable number of elements and subelements with different names (this would go into a function that takes in different initial data frames).
Which would be the best way to accomplish this, preferably with apply functions?
My best attempt:
sapply(mylist, setNames, paste(names(mylist), mylist, sep='-'))


sapply(names(mylist), \(x) setNames(mylist[[x]], paste(x, mylist[[x]], sep = "-")), USE.NAMES = TRUE)
#> $Patient
#> Patient-Pat1 Patient-Pat2 Patient-Pat3 
#>       "Pat1"       "Pat2"       "Pat3" 
#> 
#> $Cycle
#> Cycle-C1 Cycle-C2 
#>     "C1"     "C2"


I'm going to go with this, cause it's the syntax I understand the most and it's all base. Thanks!

Another with purrr's map2 and set_name.
Differences:
-- No map(map(..))
-- No [] or [[]]
new_list <- map2(
  mylist, names(mylist), 
  \(x, y) purrr::set_names(x, \(xx) paste0(y, "-", xx)))

Output:
> new_list
$Patient
Patient-Pat1 Patient-Pat2 Patient-Pat3 
      "Pat1"       "Pat2"       "Pat3" 

$Cycle
Cycle-C1 Cycle-C2 
    "C1"     "C2" 


Would appreciate a comment on the downvote. It's just a variation with two details some people might favour.

Sorry I must've downvoted by mistake when scrolling on my phone. I've edited so I can reverse it.

Lists with one level: iterate over names with lapply()
The easiest thing is to iterate over the list names. We can pass a named vector to lapply(), so the output list will have the desired names.
lapply(
    setNames(names(mylist), names(mylist)),
    \(nm, l = mylist) setNames(l[[nm]], sprintf("%s-%s", nm, l[[nm]]))
)  
# $Patient
# Patient-Pat1 Patient-Pat2 Patient-Pat3 
#       "Pat1"       "Pat2"       "Pat3" 

# $Cycle
# Cycle-C1 Cycle-C2 
#     "C1"     "C2"

Arbitrarily deep lists
You need another approach if your list may have more than one nested level, e.g.:
mylist$nested <- list(
    list("nest1", "nest2")
)

You can use rrapply::rrapply() here which has the .xparents argument, which evaluates to the names of the parent of the current list element.
I'll pipe the below to json because it prints more nicely:
rrapply::rrapply(
    mylist,
    condition = Negate(is.list), # apply only to leafs (and not nodes)
    f = \(x, .xparents) setNames(x, sprintf("%s-%s", .xparents[1], x))
) |>
    rjson::toJSON()

Output:
{
    "Patient": {
        "Patient-Pat1": "Pat1",
        "Patient-Pat2": "Pat2",
        "Patient-Pat3": "Pat3"
    },
    "Cycle": {
        "Cycle-C1": "C1",
        "Cycle-C2": "C2"
    },
    "nested": [
        [
            {
                "nested-nest1": "nest1"
            },
            {
                "nested-nest2": "nest2"
            }
        ]
    ]
}


We can use Map.
> Map(setNames, mylist, Map(paste, names(mylist), mylist, sep='-'))
$Patient
Patient-Pat1 Patient-Pat2 Patient-Pat3 
      "Pat1"       "Pat2"       "Pat3" 

$Cycle
Cycle-C1 Cycle-C2 
    "C1"     "C2" 

